# wordpress header menu and image logo not showing after importing subdomain to another domain on cpanel

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzal5.png)

wordpress header menu and image logo not showing after importing sub subdomain to another domain on cpanel.

Comment: check console error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of null
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener (browser.js:277)

Comment: I don understand where to give the domain in console

Comment: can you give us your site url?

Comment: http://kashmiriproducts.org

Comment: I don't see ay error on your website... where is it?

Comment: Image url not showing in logo and header menu items are not showing on page

Comment: Now it's working properly after making changes from admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to change siteurl and home in wp_options table

Comment: I have already changed siteurl and home still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your page source and establish the links of the header and image. if you used `wp_meta_data` to save the code then it still has the link with sub-directory on it ie (example.com/sub-domain/header.jpg). If the first options(wp_meta_data ) is right You will need to update the image location to remove sub-domain to make the image show up.